# Hide <li> without creating empty row

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a list item by using the following code (for example)

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li style="visibility:hidden">Milk</li>
  <li>tea</li>
</ol>
```

But unfornately, it renders as follows with an empty row:

```
1. Coffee

3. Tea
```

What I want is simply like this:

```
1. Coffee
2. Tea
```

I am asking if there is a neat way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `<!-- <li>Milk</li> -->` is out of the question?

Comment: On what event is the list item meant to be removed/hidden? Is there some kind of logic behind it, or should it always be the second `li`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "display:none" instead of "visibility:hidden"

**EDIT:** visibility: hidden makes an element invisible but while keeping it in the flow of the DOM, so it still occupies the same space it would if it weren't invisible, meanwhile display: none treats it as if that element isn't there to begin with

Comment: should have answered, making an example before answering: http://jsfiddle.net/MqBUt/

Comment: good answer, but for future questioners, it would be good to explain *why* you use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden`.