# Hide li if broken image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images where each image is wrapped in a ***li***:

```
<li><a href='http://www.so.com'><img src='http://www.so.com/1.jpg'></a></li>
```

How can I hide this entire ***li*** if image 1.jpg is broken as if it never existed in the DOM?

I found some good js on how to [hide the image](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/better-broken-image-handling/) and learned from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571546/hide-li-without-creating-empty-row) that I want to `display:none` so I don't create an empty row. But I'm having trouble putting these together.

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle of this issue ?

Comment: @karthikr Ill start working on that right now and edit the question with the link. Thank you, good idea.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H7Aq7/6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `onerror` handler for the image:

```
<li><a href='http://www.so.com'>
<img src='http://www.so.com/1.jpg' onerror='hideContainer(this)'>
</a></li>

// this function must be in the global scope
function hideContainer(el) {
    $(el).closest("li").hide();
}
```

Or, you could even just remove it if you really want it as if it never existing in the DOM:

```
// this function must be in the global scope
function hideContainer(el) {
    $(el).closest("li").remove();
}
```

---

If you don't want to put an `onerror` handler in the HTML (the only reliable place you can put it) then you can hide the images initially and then check `.complete` when your jQuery runs and if the image is not yet complete, then install a `.load()` handler like this:

CSS:

```
/* use some more specific selector than this */
li {display: none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$("li img").each(function() {
    if (this.complete) {
        // img already loaded successfully, show it
        $(this).closest("li").show();
    } else {
        // not loaded yet so install a .load handler to see if it loads
        $(this).load(function() {
            // loaded successfully so show it
            $(this).closest("li").show();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Chris - I added another solution too, but I think the first one is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery there is .error event handler http://api.jquery.com/error/.

Example:

```
$('img').error(function(event) {
   $(this).closest('li').hide();     

});
```

Comment: Several problems with this.  1) this will only handle the first img that has an error. 2) `this` is not a jQuery object.  3) Errors may occur BEFORE you can run your jQuery to install the error handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have modified it .

Comment: You still haven't dealt with the third issue.

Comment: @Chris No worries mate!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can set your `<li>` to load ONLY IF the `<img>` loads.  [Read along here.](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

HTML starts as:

```
<li style="display: none;"><a href='http://www.so.com'><img src='http://www.so.com/1.jpg' id="imgOne" class="imgSet"></a></li>
```

Either give it a class if it's part of a group, an ID if it's very specific and you just want that one, or select all the images on the page if you want.  For my example I'll use the class to select it as a group.

jQuery:

```
$('.imgSet').load(function() {
    $(this).parents('li').show();
});
```

Basically it's hidden until the image loads.

Comment: The image may very well load before you get your `.load()` handler attached (like if the image is in the cache) so you would miss the load event.

Comment: I think he only wants to be sure not to accidentally load an extra bullet point in case there is no image

Comment: @Deryck -- This is my fault for not being clear enough. There are no bullet points, but thank you for showing this, very interesting.

Comment: @Deryck - but if you miss the `.load()` event which is easy to do if the image is cached, then you will never show a successfully loaded image.  This is a common problem with installing event handlers AFTER the DOM has been parsed.  Some events may have already occurred before you get the event handler in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<img id='any' src="https://invalid.com" onerror="document.getElementById(this.id).remove()" >
```

on error handle the image and if not found get its id and remove itself from the DOM